# JavaScript debugging in Internet Explorer (all scripts on page)

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am new to a project in mature stage. There are many JS scripts and libraries on one of the pages, jQuery is used intensively. There is a weird error in IE7/8 only: somewhere in the middle of the page scripts execution jQuery object becomes undefined, so everything else stops working.

There are two scripts specified in the middle of HTML, say, like this:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

In the end of the `script1` a variable called `jQuery` contains an object as expected, but in the beginning  of the `script2` variable `jQuery` is already undefined. What happens in between?

Please, any ideas where to look and how to debug!

Is there a way to control the consequency of script execusion and debug the WHOLE consequent js (including all js includes) on one page?

Thank you! :)

**UPDATE**. I made a patch: in the end of the `script1` I backup the variable:

```
var jQueryBackup = jQuery;
```

In the beginning of the `script2` I restore it:

```
if (!jQuery && jQueryBackup) jQuery = jQueryBackup;
```

It made the script work, but does not explain how could a variable become undefined in between two scripts (I see it as literally between two lines of code).

Comment: cant help you without the code ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `<script>` in the middle of the HTML ? Try to put them into the `<head>`

```
<head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: JS is a interpreted language.The browser execute line by line. It haven't the same comportement if it's in the <body> or in the <head>.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to debug , this what i would do :

```
$.getScript("script1.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log('script1 is loaded');
  $.getScript("script2.js").done(function(s,t){
     console.log('script1.js is loaded');
  });
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  console.log( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

now you can debug it , you can also use native javascript and use onload.
if you need example , let me know.

example : ( this solution will work for IE8+, firefox, chrome )

```
function handleOnLoad() {
    // do the same here for the script.2 file
}
function IEhandleOnLoad() {
     if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') {
           handleOnLoad();
        }
}
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.onreadystatechange = IEhandleOnLoad;
s.onload = handleOnLoad;
s.src = 'script1.js';
```